# Invalid grant Google Service Account or 'unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens'

Tags: python, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to get/download email archives in a cloudStorage bucket. I generate exports in Google Vault w/. This emails, but I'm get stucked when I try to download them.

I'm using this code:

```py
scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control"]
service_account_file = r"credentials\token.json"
currenth_month = current_month
  
creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_file, scopes=scopes, subject=execution_email)

storage = build("storage", "v1", credentials=creds)


    for bucket in files_to_download_dict:
        object_name = files_to_download_dict[bucket]["object_name"]
        files_request = storage.objects().get_media(bucket=bucket, object=object_name)

        directory = r"C:...\test"
        output_folder = path.join(directory, current_month)
        if not path.isdir(output_folder):
            mkdir(output_folder)

        file_name_path = rf"C:file_path"

        with FileIO(file_name_path, mode="w") as data_buffer:
            download = MediaIoBaseDownload(data_buffer, files_request)
            done = False
            while not done:
                status, done = download.next_chunk()
```

I got some things from the API documentation, but I have 2 different situations:

1. I use an old functional key service account. When I try to download, I get this error:

```
invalid grant, not valid user id or email
```

2. I use a new key from the same service account w/ all scopes I need and I get something like: Client failed to get access token or doesn't have access to the scopes you need.

I don't know where the problem lies. I have already tried to use normal google credentials (web app -> I use this on other modules), but I know that I can't download in this way.

I have already tried lots of different solutions found on Stack Overflow here but none of them worked for me.

Does someone have an idea on how I could solve this problem?

Comment: You can simplify and increase the portability of your code using [Application Default Credentials](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-server.md#application-default-credentials). The error is unfamiliar to me but (!) as long as the Service Account has been granted a role on Cloud Storage, this should work. Did you grant the Service Account a Cloud Storage role? (see [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions))

Comment: Not relevant to this issue but FYI, Google provides at least two sets of client libraries. You're using the API Client Library for Cloud Storage, there's also a [Cloud Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python). Google prefers the Cloud Client Libraries over the API Client Libraries **but** you should decide what's best for you.